# NSView does not resize when window changes to full screen

Tags: macos, nsview, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

When the cocoa application starts, the NSWindow automatically change to full screen resolution. However, the custom view in the window does not resize at all. I am using auto layout so I thought it should change automatically.

I tried to resize the frame in this function but it does work still:

```
 -(void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification{
        // windowView - is custom view in NSWindow
        [self.windowView setFrame:self.window.frame];
 }
```

Here is the screenshot: (view not in full size mode.)

[image]

Here is the view in full size mode. I have no idea why the view does not enlarge with window.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to select these views in Interface Builder, and check the '**Size Inspector**' as below.

[image]

Comment: For your case, you need to select the view (with background image), and make all 4 red lines around the view visible here.

Comment: But I use auto layout in every view, so I have to change all back to non auto layout. Or I only need to change that specific view?

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure since I didn't use 'Auto Layout' before, ps: using it will cause your app to target to 10.7 and above. However, I believe 'Auto Layout' is not that smart to help you decide the alignment of these views, you can have a try by disabling 'Auto Layout' and let's see if it would work.